# Matlab changing array value in error when appending matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, append

I have a very strange bug in MATLAB (R2016a) where appending a ones array using vertcat (or using regular appending with `[A; B]`) results in a matrix where the ones have been scaled down to 0.0001 instead of 1. Multiplying the ones matrix by 10000 fixes the issue but I would like to know why 0.0001 is being appended instead of 1. Here is the code:

`temp = ones([1,307200]);
new_coords = vertcat(world_coords, temp);
new_coords`

which results in columns like the following being outputted:

`0.4449
0.3673
1.8984
0.0001`

The type for `world_coords` is double, so I don't think typecasting is the issue.

Comment: What is the range of world_coords (min,max)? Are you sure there is no 10^4 before the output?

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. The issue was the matrix has 307200 rows so the 10^4 was being swallowed by the rest of the output. Silly problem. I can mark your answer as correct if you'd like. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the output is scaled due to the range of the the values in `world_coords`. You should see in the first line of the output a scaling factor of `1.0e+4`.

You can change the output format for example with:

```
format long
```

For more details see: [format](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html)